# How to update property binding when changing the culture of the application at runtime in WPF .net core 5

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, data-binding, cultureinfo

I am trying to make my WPF app support two languages.. but I'm facing an issue when trying to bind `DataTime` DP to a `TextBlock` inside a `UserControl` and changing the current culture at runtime.

**The `DateTime` format doesn't change to the updated Culture rather it only changes when restarting the app then stay static.**

My Code:

App.xaml.cs

```
    public App()
        {
            CultureInfo CultureInformation = new CultureInfo("en-UK");
            CultureInformation.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
            CultureInformation.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern = "ddd, dd/MM/yyyy";
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = CultureInformation;
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = CultureInformation;
        }
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
                private void UpdateLanguage(string Language)
                {
                    LanguageComboBox.SelectedValue = Properties.Settings.Default.Language = Language;
                    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                    //
                    ResourceDictionary Dictionary = new();
                    Dictionary.Source = new Uri(@$"..\Languages\{Language}.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
                    Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
                    Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(Dictionary);
                    //
                    if (Language == "العربية")
                    {
                        CultureInfo CultureInformation = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ar-EG");
                        CultureInformation.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
                        CultureInformation.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern = "ddd, dd/MM/yyyy";
                        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInformation;
                        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInformation;
                    }
                    else if (Language == "English")
                    {
                        CultureInfo CultureInformation = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-UK");
                        CultureInformation.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
                        CultureInformation.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern = "ddd, dd/MM/yyyy";
                        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInformation;
                        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInformation;
                    }
                }
```

ConverterCulture

```
    public class CultureAwareBinding : Binding
    {
        public CultureAwareBinding()
        {
            ConverterCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        }
    }
```

UserControl.xaml

```
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="5" FontSize="14" FontFamily="{StaticResource Segoe Semibold}" Foreground="{DynamicResource BackgroundBrush}">
                <TextBlock Text="{local:CultureAwareBinding Path=StartTime, StringFormat={}{0:hh:mm tt}}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="" FontSize="12" FontFamily="{StaticResource Segoe Icons}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{local:CultureAwareBinding Path=EndTime, StringFormat={}{0:hh:mm tt}}"/>
            </TextBlock>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Answer**

App.xaml.cs

```
        public App()
        {
            CultureInfo CultureInformation = new CultureInfo("en-US");
            CultureInformation.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
            CultureInformation.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern = "ddd, dd/MM/yyyy";
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = CultureInformation;
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = CultureInformation;
            //
            XmlLanguage language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInformation.IetfLanguageTag);
            const BindingFlags kField = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly;
            typeof(XmlLanguage).GetField("_equivalentCulture", kField).SetValue(language, CultureInformation);
            typeof(XmlLanguage).GetField("_compatibleCulture", kField).SetValue(language, CultureInformation);
            typeof(XmlLanguage).GetField("_specificCulture", kField).SetValue(language, CultureInformation);
            FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(language));
        }
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
        private void UpdateLanguage(string Language)
        {
            LanguageComboBox.SelectedValue = Properties.Settings.Default.Language = Language;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            //
            ResourceDictionary Dictionary = new();
            Dictionary.Source = new Uri(@$"..\Languages\{Language}.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
            Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
            Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(Dictionary);
            //
            if (Language == "العربية")
            {
                CultureInfo CultureInformation = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ar-EG");
                CultureInformation.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
                CultureInformation.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern = "ddd, dd/MM/yyyy";
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInformation;
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInformation;
                //
                XmlLanguage language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInformation.IetfLanguageTag);
                const BindingFlags kField = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly;
                typeof(XmlLanguage).GetField("_equivalentCulture", kField).SetValue(language, CultureInformation);
                typeof(XmlLanguage).GetField("_compatibleCulture", kField).SetValue(language, CultureInformation);
                typeof(XmlLanguage).GetField("_specificCulture", kField).SetValue(language, CultureInformation);
                this.Language = language;
            }
            else if (Language == "English")
            {
                CultureInfo CultureInformation = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
                CultureInformation.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
                CultureInformation.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern = "ddd, dd/MM/yyyy";
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInformation;
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInformation;
                //
                XmlLanguage language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInformation.IetfLanguageTag);
                const BindingFlags kField = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly;
                typeof(XmlLanguage).GetField("_equivalentCulture", kField).SetValue(language, CultureInformation);
                typeof(XmlLanguage).GetField("_compatibleCulture", kField).SetValue(language, CultureInformation);
                typeof(XmlLanguage).GetField("_specificCulture", kField).SetValue(language, CultureInformation);
                this.Language = language;
            }
        }
```

There is **NO** **ConverterCulture** class

```
    public class CultureAwareBinding : Binding
    {
        public CultureAwareBinding()
        {
            ConverterCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        }
    }
```

UserControl.xaml **(Normal Binding)**

```
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="5" FontSize="14" FontFamily="{StaticResource Segoe Semibold}" Foreground="{DynamicResource BackgroundBrush}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=StartTime, StringFormat={}{0:hh:mm tt}}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="" FontSize="12" FontFamily="{StaticResource Segoe Icons}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=EndTime, StringFormat={}{0:hh:mm tt}}"/>
            </TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no ready-made simple solution that can be applied to all cases.
The decision depends on what you think is valid for its implementation and how you have implemented the bindings.

1. Let's say you have all the bindings to the Window data context.
   And in fact you need to call the rendering of the DataContext view on all Windows.
   Then you can use this method in Code Behind App:

```cs
    public static async void RerenderAllDataContext()
    {
        var windows = Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().ToList();

        var dataContextes = windows.ToDictionary(w => w, w => w.DataContext);

        var dispatcher = Current.Dispatcher;

        await dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => windows.ForEach(w => w.DataContext = null));
        await dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => windows.ForEach(w => w.DataContext = dataContextes[w]));
    }
```

But this method has its drawbacks: it redraws all windows, the state of UI elements is reset (for example, the cursor position in the TextBox or SelectedItem), there may be bindings not to the Data Context, etc.

2. If there are not many bindings for which you need to take into account the culture, or they are created not only to the Data Context, then all that remains is to call the redrawing of all such bindings.
   With minimal changes, this can be done by using MiltiBinding instead of Binding, in which one of the bindings (usually the last one) will use the property with the current culture.
   For such a MiltiBinding, the converter returns the first value of the received array of values ​​(if there are two of them).
   For simplicity's sake, you can derive a class from MiltiBinding to approximate its application as closely as possible to a regular Binding.

**Supplementing the answer in one more way:**

3. You can use the FrameworkElement.Language property to set the culture.
   This is a dependency property so you can bind it.
   Property value is inherited by children (similar to DataContext).
   If you set it to the Window, then all the elements in it will also take the same value.
   Or you can set it to some specific element.

Additional types can be declared to reduce the XAML code.
Example.
Static class for setting culture globally:

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace Wpf.Data
{
    public static class LanguageAware
    {
        public static XmlLanguage CurrentLanguage { get; private set; } = XmlLanguage.Empty;
        public static event EventHandler CurrentLanguageChanged;
        public static void SetCurrentLanguage(XmlLanguage currentLanguage)
        {
            if (currentLanguage == null)
            {
                currentLanguage = XmlLanguage.Empty;
            }

            if (!Equals(CurrentLanguage, currentLanguage))
            {
                CurrentLanguage = currentLanguage;
                CurrentLanguageChanged?.Invoke(null, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

An example of its use:

```xml
    <Window.Resources>
        <sys:DateTime x:Key="date">12.31.2021 15:47</sys:DateTime>
    </Window.Resources>
    <UniformGrid Columns="1">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(wpfdata:LanguageAware.CurrentLanguage)}" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource date}, StringFormat=\{0:F\}}"
                 Language="{Binding Path=(wpfdata:LanguageAware.CurrentLanguage)}"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource date}, StringFormat=\{0:F\}}"/>
        <Button Content="Russian" Click="OnCultureClick" CommandParameter="RU" Margin="10"/>
        <Button Content="English-USA" Click="OnCultureClick" CommandParameter="En-Us" Margin="10"/>
    </UniformGrid>
    <x:Code><![CDATA[
        private void OnCultureClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string lang = ((Button)sender).CommandParameter as string;
            if (lang == null)
                LanguageAware.SetCurrentLanguage(null);
            else
                LanguageAware.SetCurrentLanguage(XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(lang));
        }]]>
    </x:Code>
```

Markup extension to replace clicker in XAML with command:

```cs
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace Wpf.Data
{

    [MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(ICommand))]
    public class LanguageCommandExtension : MarkupExtension
    {
        private static readonly LanguageCommand command = new LanguageCommand();
        public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged() => command.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return command;
        }
        private class LanguageCommand : ICommand
        {
            private readonly EventHandler requerySuggested;

            /// <inheritdoc cref="ICommand.CanExecuteChanged"/>
            public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

            private static readonly Dispatcher dispatcher = Application.Current.Dispatcher;

            /// <summary> The method that raises the event <see cref="CanExecuteChanged"/>.</summary>
            public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
            {
                if (dispatcher.CheckAccess())
                {
                    invalidate();
                }
                else
                {
                    _ = dispatcher.BeginInvoke(invalidate);
                }
            }
            private readonly Action invalidate;
            public LanguageCommand()
            {
                invalidate = () => CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);

                requerySuggested = (o, e) => CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested += requerySuggested;
            }

            /// <inheritdoc cref="ICommand.CanExecute(object)"/>
            public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
            {
                if (parameter == null || parameter is XmlLanguage)
                {
                    return true;
                }

                try
                {
                    if (parameter is string str)
                    {
                        return XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(str) != null;
                    }
                    if (parameter is CultureInfo culture)
                    {
                        str = culture.Name;
                        return XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(str) != null;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                { }

                return false;
            }

            /// <inheritdoc cref="ICommand.Execute(object)"/>
            public void Execute(object parameter)
            {
                if (parameter is XmlLanguage language)
                { }
                else if (parameter == null)
                {
                    language = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (parameter is string str)
                        {
                            language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(str);
                        }
                        else if (parameter is CultureInfo culture)
                        {
                            str = culture.Name;
                            language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(str);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw new InvalidCastException(nameof(parameter));
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(parameter));
                    }
                }
                LanguageAware.SetCurrentLanguage(language);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

An example of its use with setting the language for the panel:

```xml
    <Window.Resources>
        <sys:DateTime x:Key="date">12.31.2021 15:47</sys:DateTime>
    </Window.Resources>
    <UniformGrid Columns="1"
                 Language="{Binding Path=(wpfdata:LanguageAware.CurrentLanguage)}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(wpfdata:LanguageAware.CurrentLanguage)}" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource date}, StringFormat=\{0:F\}}"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource date}, StringFormat=\{0:F\}}"/>
        <Button Content="Russian" Command="{wpfdata:LanguageCommand}" CommandParameter="RU" Margin="10"/>
        <Button Content="English-USA" Command="{wpfdata:LanguageCommand}" CommandParameter="En-Us" Margin="10"/>
    </UniformGrid>
```

Markup extension for the Language property:

```cs
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace Wpf.Data
{
    [MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(Binding))]
    public class LanguageAwareExtension : Binding
    {
        public LanguageAwareExtension()
        {
            Path = new PropertyPath(
                "(0)",
                typeof(LanguageAware).GetProperty(nameof(LanguageAware.CurrentLanguage)));
            ConverterCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        }
    }
}
```

An example of its use with setting the language for the Window:

```xml
<Window ----------------------------
        ----------------------------
        Language="{wpfdata:LanguageAware}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <sys:DateTime x:Key="date">12.31.2021 15:47</sys:DateTime>
    </Window.Resources>
    <UniformGrid Columns="1">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(wpfdata:LanguageAware.CurrentLanguage)}" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource date}, StringFormat=\{0:F\}}"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource date}, StringFormat=\{0:F\}}"/>
        <Button Content="Russian" Command="{wpfdata:LanguageCommand}" CommandParameter="RU" Margin="10"/>
        <Button Content="English-USA" Command="{wpfdata:LanguageCommand}" CommandParameter="En-Us" Margin="10"/>
    </UniformGrid>
</Window>
```

Comment: can u please give me an example of how to implement the second option as i'm not familiar with multibinding in wpf yet in addition to that, the first solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: See the addition to my answer.
I added another implementation option and extended examples with code there.

Comment: I haven't looked closely at your code.
The fact is that when the value of the source changes, the Binding is not re-created.
Therefore, the Binding.ConverterCulture property (which you set in the CultureAwareBinding class) will be the same as it was when the Window was initialized.
Therefore, the first option I proposed will not work for your implementation.

Comment: thank you for your reply <3.. I Managed to solve this issue by adding this code this.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInformation.Name); to UpdateLanguage(string Language) method. but I faced another issue as using this way overrides my short/long date patterns.. what is the problem with that?

Comment: finally solved following this: https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/1946#issuecomment-534564980 .. I'm gonna post the answer and many thanks for your time.

Comment: The final code https://stackoverflow.com/a/69367774/16248076

Comment: Your method is simple and will work well if you have a single window in the Application and the method is executed in the Code Behind of the Window.
It was not clear from your question.
Therefore, it did not occur to me that you are interested in installing the language in a single Window.
And because of this, I gave, probably, a too complicated solution.

Comment: anyways.. thank U & of course your solution will help another one in the future. and i can use properties.setting.default.changed event to track when the language is changed to update it in any other window but now I am using only one window with this app

Answer (score 0):

You may need to notify your WPF form controls. just require raising PropertyChanged for CurrentCulture
here's an [example](https://www.codinginfinity.me/posts/localization-of-a-wpf-app-the-simple-approach/)

Comment: i implemented iNotifyPropertyChanged in my window and called notifypropertychanged(nameof(currentculture)) but nothing changed. can u show me how to do that if you have ever experienced a situation like this?